# Assigning Excel VBA ActiveX ListBox .Selection to a TextBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm trying to click a selection on an ActiveX ListBox and have value assigned to a TextBox then clear the ListBox. It seems straightforward but I'm 
getting 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on the first line

This is what I'm using:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox3").Object.Value = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Selection
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Selection = ""

End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how to make this word or resources to search are appreciated.

Comment: Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Just found that ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox3").Object.Text = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value works for getting the ListBox selection into the TextBox.   And ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value = "" seems to put a null in the ListBox value.  When I try to msgbox it I get the error 'Invalid use of null.  But the ListBox selection is still highlighted and I'd like that to be unselected if possible.

Comment: I've tried using each of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654252/reset-listbox-selection-in-vba but can't get any of them to remove the highlighting from the listbox item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be cleaner written like this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Text
  ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
End Sub
```

But there is a problem: the second line doesn't work inside the `ListBox1_Change` event (because it would create an infinite loop). I tried with `Application.EnableEvents = False`, but it didn't help.

I think you need to put the reset of the selection in another event, like the `KeyUp` or `MouseUp`.

Comment: I think I see.  The deselecting itself is a "click" event so the clickevent sub keeps getting called?

Comment: Yes. In similar cases often you put `Application.EnableEvents = False` before and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after changing the object that would fire the event. But in this case Excel seems to prevent you from  even trying.

Comment: ok. thanks.  For your mouseup suggestion, how do I determine the X and Y values?

Comment: I suggested to use the `MouseUp` or `KeyUp` events because they are fired after the `Click` (I think). You don't need x and y.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks Stenci.  I'll ask a Mouseup Question separately on the board.