# Excel VBA Listbox MultiSelect To Fill Other ListBox - VBA code with multi page gives error

Tags: vba

I am creating a Excel VBA Listbox MultiSelect To Fill Other ListBox using the video tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWTEUWqlQAc

Basically, what this means is, "Excel, if I select these items from ListBox 1 which obtains a range of values from Excel Column C, return me a list of values from Excel Column A on the same row"

However, I keep getting an error message "Compile error Invalid Use of Property"

This highlights this code here:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is it because I am using Multi-page or something with this code?

I have tried re-watching that damned tutorial but nothing seems to be working.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)


'find lastrow

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of Emails").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


'clear listbox1
Me.ListBox2.Value

'not just one value, but whichever were selected
For SelItm = LBound(Me.ListBox1.Email) To UBound(Me.ListBox1.Email)
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(SelItm) = True Then
       'It is selected

        curVal = Me.ListBox1.List(SelItm, 0)

        For X = 2 To lastrow
            If emails.Cells(X, "c") = curVal Then
                'found a match; populate listbox2
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of Emails").Cells(X, "a")
            End If
        Next X


    End If


Next SelItm


End Sub
```

I cannot get rid of the error message no matter how hard I try. Like wtf is "Compile error Invalid Use of Property" ? I did exactly as the Youtube guide did.

Appreciate if anyone can offer any kind assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it complaining about `Me.ListBox2.Value`? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056444/7404943) about clearing listbox (selection or whole list)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment Barbsan, however I am still confused.

Excel highlights this here:
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

^Which means this is the 1 with the problem. But I can't figure out what the problem is because this was how the tutorial did it and they are right.

Why do you suggest clearing listbox? Sorry. Pretty new to VBA here.

Comment: I don't suggest, I see that you have comment `'clear listbox1` followed by `Me.ListBox2.Value` which I expect to cause the error. Excel sometimes struggles to show the exact line that causes the error. I've just chosen random moment from your link https://youtu.be/dWTEUWqlQAc?t=533 and there's `Me.ListBox2.Clear` instead of this line

Comment: Hi, I Changed this

    'clear listbox1

    Me.ListBox2.Value

to

> Me.listbox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Me.listbox1.Value = ""

> Me.listbox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti


But I don't think it is working.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? In your video there's a `Me.ListBox2.Clear` on that line

Comment: Hi, yes I understand that. But what I don't understand is why this is a problem and I do not know what to do...

Comment: So you want to get explanation why `Me.ListBox2.Value` causes that error? About "what to do" I'd recommend to follow your tutorial and use `Me.ListBox2.Clear`

Comment: Do you declare `lastrow` anywhere? Like `Dim lastrow As Integer` or something similar?

Comment: Hi Barbsan,

Thank you for your reply. Nothing works for me at the moment. I am still receiving an error message even though I changed i to Me.ListBox2.Clear

With regards to your comment about lastrow, i have this code in Listbox1 mouse up and Listbox2 click:

`lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of Emails").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Could you comment all lines but this with `lastrow` (or create some new sub and copy that line) and check whether it fails or not?

Comment: Hi, I commented all lines with 'lastrow except for the 1 you mentioned, but nothing seems to be working.

Not sure how to proceed with the other method.

Do you mind if I send my excel softcopy file to you?

Thanks!